# Gradle syncing lock

Tags: android-studio-3.5

My android gradle is kept on syncing even all the process under it are fully completed and got 
 the green tick mark on their left side but the top header which is as in my case is 
  **MegaFlip:syncing** this header shows that syncing is in the progress while all the sub tasks 
 under it are entirely completed.I cannot even explore my project files.
So any one have idea why this is happening?One thing to add is i created this project in the 
 older window and now today i install fresh window and install android studio and try to open this project 
 but it kept on syncing.Please suggest me a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

All the problems I had syncing gradle were solved once I disabled firewall.